# VBA - Copy information to new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to do something that sounds incredibly simple but I can't figure out how to fit it into existing VBA code. The code below cycles through a pivot table 1 item at a time and copies that pivot table data out to a new workbook and emails to the staff member

All i need to add in is for it to copy (just values and formatting) a 13x2 table in the range E15:S16 on the same sheet as the pivot table, into the new workbook in the tab I've named "Monthly Forecast". with the loops etc i'm not sure how to get this into the code so it copies the pivot data and then the monthly forecast into the separate tab

Hope that makes sense, any help would be wonderful :)

```
Option Explicit

Sub PivotSurvItems()
Dim i As Integer
Dim sItem As String
Dim sName As String
Dim sEmail  As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    .PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
    With .PivotFields("Staff")
        '---hide all items except item 1
        .PivotItems(1).Visible = True
        For i = 2 To .PivotItems.Count
            .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
        Next
        For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
            .PivotItems(i).Visible = True
            If i <> 1 Then .PivotItems(i - 1).Visible = False
            sItem = .PivotItems(i)
            ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
            Selection.Copy
            Workbooks.Add

            With ActiveWorkbook

                .Sheets(1).Cells(1).PasteSpecial _
                Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:R").AutoFit
                ActiveSheet.Range("A2").AutoFilter
                sName = Range("C" & 2)
                sEmail = Range("N" & 2)

                Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
                Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete
                Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete
                Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete
                Columns(10).EntireColumn.Delete

                ActiveSheet.Name = "FCW"

                Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Monthly Forecast"

                Worksheets("FCW").Activate

            'create folder
                On Error Resume Next
                MkDir "C:\Temp\FCW" & "\" & sName
                On Error GoTo 0


                .SaveAs "C:\Temp\FCW" & "\" & sName & "\" & sItem & " " & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY") & ".xlsx", _
                    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

                  Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

                        On Error Resume Next
                        With OutMail
                            .To = sEmail
                            .CC = ""
                            .BCC = ""
                            .Subject = "Planning Spreadsheet"
                            .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
                            .Send
                        End With
                        On Error GoTo 0

                        Set OutMail = Nothing
                        Set OutApp = Nothing



                .Close
            End With


        Next i
    End With
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing visibility and cycling through all the items in the pivot table, assign the values to a 'table' (a range) and pass it to where you want it to go (it's much faster than using Excel's `.copy` and `.PasteSpecial` in VBA.

Also, I suggest that you copy all the data to an 'outputs' worksheet in the same workbook. When all the data has been copied, export that specific outputs worksheet into a new workbook. This way you avoid copying and pasting data between two different workbooks which can be prone to errors.

In your code, I would remove everything from the item cycling down until the Temp folder creation and replace it with something like the following:

```
'Copy values
  Set rStartCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'Specify the top-left corner cell of the data you wish to copy
  Set rTable_1 = ActiveSheet.Range(rStartCell, ActiveSheet.Range("Z" & rStartCell.End(xlDown).Row)) 'Change the Z column to the last column of the data you wish to copy. You can automate this by using something like Range(A1).end(xltoright).columns.count formula to grab the number of columns.
  Debug.Print "rTable_1: " & rTable_1.Address & " -> " & rTable_1.Rows.Count & " x " & rTable_1.Columns.Count 'good to test exactly what you're copying

  'Paste Values
  Set rStartCell = Outputs.Range("A1") 'Change A1 to the cell of where you want to paste on the Outputs worksheet in your original workbook.
  Set rTable_2 = Outputs.Range(rStartCell, rStartCell.Offset(rTable_1.Rows.Count - 1, rTable_1.Columns.Count - 1))
  Debug.Print "rTable_2: " & rTable_2.Address & " -> " & rTable_2.Rows.Count & " x " & rTable_2.Columns.Count
  rTable_2.Value = rTable_1.Value
  rTable_1.Copy
  rTable_2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats 'to copy/paste those formats you need

  'Copy Worksheet and open it in a new workbook
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NAME OF OUTPUTS SHEET").Copy 'Using ThisWorkbook to point to the workbook holding this code.
  ActiveSheet.Name = "FCW"
```

You can use this method to copy/paste that other table mentioned as well.